# How do I delete a VirtualBox Snapshot

Tags: virtualbox

I created a snapshot of a Linux Vm prior to running updates. When i started the VM, I was immediately met with an error saying the Parent UUID does not match the snapshot.  I tried deleting the snapshot and got the same error.
In he VM media manager, the error is associated with one disk file that is stored on a physical disk different from the default VM location.
How do I remove this snapshot. And how do I make snapshots work for this VM?

Specs:
VBox v5.0.14
Host OS: Windows 10
Guest OS: Slackware 14.1

Comment: A comment on a down vite is always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the data disk (VHD) for this VM on a different drive from where the other VHDs are stored (and from where snapshots are stored). When you create a snapshot in this situation, the snapshot file for the VHD drive stored on the different disk is created with an invalid (all 0s) Parent UUID.

The is a third party tool called SetVHDParentUUID available on Windows to fix this.  It can be found here: http://www.mcgrane.co.uk/Article/Projects